# clearcanvas dicom image viewer

Tags: c#, image, dicom

How can I use the clear canvas Image Viewer component with my project. Say, I am going to create a windows application. I just created a Form1. How can I drag and drop the ClearCanvas viewer to my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use it in this way. I already tried it before. Most senior members from the clearcanvas forum said "that imageviewer is not designed for using in other application".
You need to change a lot of code if you want to use it. The simple way is to add their Dlls in your application and create your own imageviewer. Those dlls will produce a bitmap file from Dicom image and you can show it in your application. I have some sample code. I used it in that way.